# How do I keep Struts2 from appending jsessionid to the URL (on redirects)?

Tags: java, session, servlets, struts2

I want to keep the jsessionid parameter out of the URLs generated by Struts, but can't seem to find a configuration parameter or similar. To be honest, I don't even know exactly at which level this is handled.

Specifically, Struts (or the servlet engine) puts a sessionid in the URL when it's redirecting with a 302 and the session has not been established before (i. e. the redirect is in response to a request that sent no `Cookie` header). The response also contains a `Set-Cookie` header.

Generally, I just don't want the session id in the URL, ever. No cookies, no session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check what's your servlet container offers to solve this problem. Alternatively you can write a filter to get rid of jsessionid. Hae a look here for details: http://seamframework.org/Documentation/RemovingJSESSIONIDFromYourURLsAndFixingScache

Comment: The link is Not Found